# How to create a public variable in a private module

Tags: ms-access, vba

Basically It's a login form and i'm trying to save the ID which is the Me.CBOUsername.Column(0) but I get an error when i try to call it in another form.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public ID_ As String
Private Sub Command4_Click()
    Dim strCBOPass As String
    Dim strPassword As String

    strCBOPass = Me.CBOUsername.Column(1)
    strPassword = Me.txtpassword

    If strCBOPass = strPassword Then
        MsgBox "Login Successful!"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1"
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
        ID_ = Me.CBOUsername.Column(0)

    Else
        MsgBox "login Unsuccessful!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Add a public module to your project an declare the variable there. There are ways to access the variable the way you are declaring it but unless you have very specific reasons to need it declared within your form's module, you shouldn't.

Comment: Basically while the user is logging in on clicking login if it's successful it takes the user's ID used which is the thing I need in my next form but I can't call it

Comment: If you declare the variable in public module you can set/call it from anywhere.

Comment: Call it outside the private sub?

Comment: Decalre it outside the form Class Object. Like in a Module, same way you did in the Form.

Comment: Yes. If you put the line `Public ID_ As String` on any module that is not attached to a form/report then you can use `ID_` anywhere.

Comment: Aren't global variables frowned upon because they could accidentally be changed. Maybe a temp table to store it in a table, this means it would take a specific effort to add, change, or delete the ID_ by accident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be a little easier to explain this way.

As an example of a global variable:

```
Public Global_Variable1 as String

Public Sub Procedure1()
    Global_Variable1 = "Test"
End Sub

Public Sub Procedure2()
    Call Procedure1
    MsgBox (Global_Variable1)  'return Test
End Sub
```

[image]

Add the module by right-clicking, and using Insert > Module

Comment: Sorry, the Project in the screen cap is part of the VBA editor. (You can also use the menu on the VBA editor, from Insert > Module)

Comment: i found that okay, so shall i put the entire login code in there then just call that inside the private sub?

Comment: @Billy <Ctrl>-G will get you into the VB Editor

Comment: So what would i define the ID_ as in the module for me to then run it in the actual form? and would i need to call the public variable in each form? how would I call it in another form as well

Comment: Once you have defined your variable as Public in a module, then just use it as a normal variable. You don't need to do anything special to use it. Just lines like `ID_ = Me.CBOUsername.Column(0)` will work in any part